# What's the term for a window cut into a hedge?

Tags: single-word-requests

French derivation, I think. At first I thought "parterre" but that's not it. I'm thinking about a window or opening cut into a tall privet hedge, usually made of yew or laurel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an image of that 'window cut into a hedge'?

Comment: I couldn't add a photo but here's a link to one. https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alamy.com%2Fstock-photo%2Ffagus-sylvatica-garden-hedge.html&psig=AOvVaw16l7qpHorbu6smO7WQk7Kg&ust=1590157876739000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJDCgPCVxekCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Comment: Good examples of *topiary*. But the first photo is English Ivy, a vine, so the cutout is really ivy growing on a structure. The ivy is not actually cut out.

Comment: *Window hedge*.

Comment: Your second one isn't a window, it's an arch over a gateway. In the case of hedges if you can walk through it it's not a window.

Answer (score 2):

How about **aperture**, which sounds like *parterre*, but is actually just a fancy word for *opening*, *hole*, or *gap*. From Lexico:

> [**aperture**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/aperture): an opening, hole, or gap

Example:

> While she was trying to find her way out of the maze, she laid eyes on her soulmate for the first time through an **aperture** in the privet hedge.

Answer (score 0):

There is this, ["The Door in the Hedge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Door_in_the_Hedge).  The author might have nonced it somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a window. And cutting them is called windowing.

> There are ways to provide a view on your property without harming the trees. One technique is called “windowing” because a “hole” is cut carefully in the dense mangroves to open up the view.
> https://www.prtree.com/blog/3-things-you-must-know-about-trimming-your-mangroves